# Clash of Clans - more gems

Tags: clash-of-clans

How do you get more gems without having to buy them? It is a pain trying to complete the building with only two builders huts.

Answer (score 0):

four words, Rocks, Bushes, and Trees

If you see a link or site that says "Free Gems" or something along those lines, it's a scam don't mess with those sites they'll shut your clash of clans account down.